# SignerInfo.CheckSignature throws out exception "Parameter is incorrect"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, digital-signature, sign

There is a method (simplified here) that verifies the digital signature. When I try to check a signed file, I get an error "Parameter is incorrect" in the method SignerInfo.CheckSignature. No matter what parameters I pass. This is happening on the production server and I cannot reproduce the same error on myself - everything works fine. The signature and certificate chain are valid. The code and certificate collection are the same for development and production servers.

```
public string Check(byte[] fileBytes)
{
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
    X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection(store.Certificates);
    store.Close();
    byte[] encodedSignedCms = fileBytes;
    SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms();
    signedCms.Decode(encodedSignedCms);
    if (signedCms.SignerInfos.Count == 0)
        return ("not found");
    SignerInfoEnumerator enumerator = signedCms.SignerInfos.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        SignerInfo current = enumerator.Current;
        try
        {
            //any of these methods will return the same error
            current.CheckSignature(true);
            current.CheckSignature(collection, true);
            current.CheckSignature(collection, false);
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            //parameter is incorrect
            return ("error");
        }
    }
    return ("success");
}
```

Error:

```
MESSAGE: parameter is incorrect
INNEREXCEPTION: null
STACKTRACE: in System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignerInfo.Verify(X509Certificate2Collection extraStore, X509Certificate2 certificate, Boolean verifySignatureOnly) in System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignerInfo.CheckSignature(X509Certificate2Collection extraStore, Boolean verifySignatureOnly) in ProjectName.Controllers.SignatureController.Check(Byte[] fileBytes). 
TARGETSITE: Void Verify(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2, Boolean)
```

Technical info:

```
ASP.NET MVC
Production: Windows Server 2016. Net Framework 4.8. IIS 10. 
Development: Windows 7 Pro or Windows Server 2016. Net Framework 4.8. Visual Studio 2015
```

What can I fix or check? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the chain was not displayed when opening any certificate. And the error "**A system-level error occurred while verifying trust**" was displayed. I found a recommendation to reinstall the crypto provider. In my case, it is Crypto Pro CSP. After that, the chain of certificates lined up correctly, and the code worked fine. Most likely this happened after the Windows update.